# Regular expression to get only the first decimal

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string of type `"12.43 some non important stuff"`, I want to get the number 12.43, but only if it is at exact position, which is 0 in this case.

`"\d+"` will return `12.43`, but it will return it even in case of `"hello world 12.43 some non important stuff"`.

Is there an easy way (maybe not regex even) to get the decimal only if it's on desired position?

Comment: @CodeCaster it is not quite a duplicate of that question, since I need a decimal. So I did not guess to search for just a character and created this one.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you're looking for, the only relevant part of your question is that what you're looking for is at the start of the line, which the duplicates shows how to do. I also highly doubt that `d+` will match `12.43`.

Comment: Well, you are right, it does not :( So apparently it's not only the start of the line that is relevant, but I guess It's yet another question

Comment: Well if you're having trouble with that, try searching something like "C# regex match literal dot".

Comment: I found the solution actually, in the comments to the answer. You can close it of course, but it does not look like full duplicate to me.

Comment: Well we really don't need a separate question for each specific regex pattern, searching for relevant questions and answers already is hard enough as it is. Your actual question was _"How can I match only from the beginning of the line"_, which is answered in the duplicate. Your secondary question, _"How can I match a literal dot"_, is answered elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `^` (start anchor)

```
^\d+
```

If you know a specific position, (say 5th) you can do the following:

```
^.{4}(\d+)
```

Comment: d+ will not match a decimal actually, I've ended up with this one: ^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?

Comment: Yeah.. it was just an example :)